# Read and Write files using Threadpool

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to read large number of small files (1000s) from AWS S3 and write them as few big partitions (100s) in AWS S3. So, I group the files in a chunks based on their size and read/write the files in threads to parallelize the whole process.

```
Threadpool(10).starmap(read_write, file_dict)

def read_write(file_dict):
     with s3fs.S3FileSystem().open(file_path, 'wb') as f
         f.write(read_file(file_dict.values()))

 def read_file(key):
    return s3fs.get_object(bucket, key).get("body").read()
```

However, I get Out Of Memory after processing about 10 - 15 group of file chunks. Anything wrong with this approach?

Comment: Instead of reading whole file into memory, you can read and write in smaller byte chunks. (Also, using threads is unlikely to speed anything up, since the bottleneck is IO - the slowest part is networking and then writing to disk... not the CPU speed.)

Comment: The files are small in size ~ 2 - 5MB each. Hope it should be okay? And Im using threads to really process files in smaller chunk to keep the memory under control otherwise I might need large instance not to increase the speed.

Comment: I would suggest using memory profiler to help narrow down what might be consuming so much memory. For simplicity, you could also try to run the solution using a single thread and see if that works.

Comment: I tried with Single thread that also failed :( so Im clue less what goes wrong?

Comment: Try using memory profiler... some can tell you exactly which line of code consumed the most memory and therefore caused your error. (Also, it would be good to know, if you are running this locally, or on some server machine, that could potentially have only few MB of memory available to begin with).